# React: Prevent remount when parent rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a component, `Split`, which takes two children. The first child will be displayed on the left hand side of the screen & the second child on the right hand side. If the screen width goes below a certain point then only the right side will be displayed and the left side will be removed from the DOM.

Example children could be a `Sidebar` component and a `Content` component. For mobile devices i don't want to display the menu, but have a special mobile menu that i pop up.

My question is: How can i remove the `Sidebar` component without unmounting & remounting the `Content` component too?

My `Content` component fetches data on `componentDidMount` and i don't want it to refetch or re-mount(thus discarding user input) again.

Basically i have something like this:

```
<Split>
  <Sidebar/>
  <Content/>
</Split>
```

And `Split`'s render method looks something like this:

```
let children;
let firstChild = this.props.children[0];
let lastChild = this.props.children.pop();
if (this.state.responsive === 'singleColumn') {
  children = (
    <div>
      <div style={{display: 'none'}}>{firstChild}</div>
      {lastChild}
    </div>
  );
} else {
  children = (
    <div>
      {firstChild}
      {lastChild}
    </div>
  );
}

return (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

Even though {lastChild} is always rendered, no matter what, it still gets unmounted and remounted each time split has to re-render!

Even having a render that looks like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.props.children.pop()}
  </div>
);
```

causes the last child(which never changes) to be unmounted & remounted before being rendered.

If i instead modify `Split` and pass the component that will always be in the DOM as an attribute like so:

```
<Split staticComponent={<Content />}>
  <Sidebar />
</Split>
```

it works fine. Then why doesn't it work when im just popping the last child like this `{this.props.children.pop()}` as opposed to this `{this.props.staticComponent}`

Is there a sane way to solve this?

Comment: I get it what you mean now, hence the delete, have you tried using css here? this is more of a problem with that no? at a certain screen size, you need to change to style on that child to display: none..hope that helps

Comment: check out this article, about half way down they do walk through a similar scenario based on screen size
https://medium.com/@jviereck/modularise-css-the-react-way-1e817b317b04#.wew0pfsyh

Comment: Well, the thing is that Split comes from a library and it's really nice and works perfectly without writing any CSS except this problem. So a pure CSS solution is not something i want. I want React to move the {lastChild} component around instead of removing and and inserting it to the DOM.

Comment: I see, and i know how i would go about to do it if i wasn't using the library to do it. But there has to be some way to not unmount the <Content> component since no matter what state or props are set it always gets rendered by Split.

Comment: does the library have media queries? if not go for it...see if it breaks shit, why not

Comment: It does. That's how it knows when to unmount the <Sidebar> component. However i'm more curious how to make React _not_ unmount the component that will always be rendered

Comment: post the code for the other components, I think you can do this with shouldCompUpdate, but only in the content one not any other one,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107172/discussion-between-oscar-linde-and-omarjmh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally managed to solve the issue! I re-wrote `Split`'s render to look something like this:

```
let left;
if (this.state.responsive !== 'singleColumn') {
  left = this.props.children.slice(0, -1);
}

return (
  <div ref="split" className={classes.join(' ')}>
    {left}
    {this.props.children[this.props.children.length-1]}
  </div>
);
```

This way the last child *always* gets rendered. Obviously `pop()` didn't work because then i modified the original array of children which triggered the weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the lifecycle method: shouldComponentUpdate:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.props.value !== nextProps.value;
}
```

If the logic inside return false, the component will not update.

check out the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html

Comment: The Split component should still re-render. But the last child passed should never be removed from the DOM. So i don't think shouldComponentUpdate will help me unfortunately :(

Comment: this should go in the component you want to control, not split

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate will only prevent the component from rendering. I want to prevent the Split component from unmounting my subcomponent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) function in the component's lifecycle.  If it returns false, according to the documentation

> If shouldComponentUpdate returns false, then render() will be completely skipped until the next state change. In addition, componentWillUpdate and componentDidUpdate will not be called.

Comment: This only prevents rendering. What i want is to prevent <Split> from unmounting & remounting my <Content> component because then it loses it's state & fetches data again on componentDidMount

Comment: So you only want to affect the <Sidebar> component?  My guess would be that that should be handled within the <Sidebar> component itself, you can pass a function through <Sidebar>'s props, and when that is called from <Split>, <Sidebar> will hide itself (upon rendering) and it will be the only one affected, thus not affecting <Content>

Comment: Yeah, i realize i could work around it like this. But i'm using a library called Grommet which has this Split component that hides the first child when the window becomes too small. However the second child is still affected by the remounting :( I need React to understand that nothing has been done with <Content> and thus it shouldn't be remounted.

Comment: Ah so the library is causing <Content> to be remounted?

Comment: Exactly. Becuase internally it does something like: if (shouldShowSidebar) { left=this.props.children[0]; } return (<div>{left}{this.props.children.pop()}</div>);

Comment: If you for sure wanted to use the library, I would use a conditional in your componentDidMount function, that way you would still render, but you wouldn't have to waste time getting resources you already have (or doing whatever it is you need to in there).  But it almost sounds like you understand the library well enough that you could write what needs to be done yourself, and not use the library in this case, because it sounds like what the library does isn't exactly what you want.

Comment: You're correct. But the problem with the components state being trashed on  unmount still persists. So i'd have to temporarily save away my data which i want to avoid.

I'm not exactly sure how to write it myself in a sane way. I updated my original question with a not-so-sane way of doing it at the bottom. Passing the component that will always be rendered via a attribute on <Split> but that isn't ideal imo.